# Is there a more efficient way to create an inverted index from a large text file?

Tags: python, performance, data-structures, text, inverted-index

```
def inverted_index(doc):
    words = word_count(doc)
    ln = 0
    for word in words:
        temp = []
        with open(doc) as file:
            for line in file:
                ln += 1
                li = line.split()
                if word in li:
                    temp.append(ln)
            words[word] = temp
    return words
```

I am trying to create an inverted index from a text file, where *words* is a dictionary with all the 19000 unique words in the file. The text file has around 5000+ lines. I want to iterate through the file and dictionary to create the inverted index that has the word followed by line numbers that the word appears but it is taking too long to compile as it is nested for loop. So is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: maybe learn algorithm from [Apache Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/)

Comment: Can you give a sample file (e.g. a small portion of the actual file) as well as what output you're expecting from this function? Also, what is `word_count()`? [Please provide enough code to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: for each word you reopen the file, you should open file once instead.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark is just a function that creates a dictionary of all the unique words in the file. I have mentioned that in my explanation.

Comment: If there are 19,000 unique words in the file, then you're reading the entire file 19,000 times (plus 1 for the initial pass in `word_count`).  A better way is to read every word in the file, adding or modifying their entries in a dictionary as you go.  Looking things up in the dictionary is much, much faster than looking things up in the file.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy thank you so much i never though about it like that, this really helped!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach to solve this, please read the notes below code for some pragmatic tips.

```
def inverted_index(doc):
    # this will open the file
    file = open(doc, encoding='utf8')
    f = file.read()
    file.seek(0)


    # Get number of lines in file
    lines = 1
    for word in f:
        if word == '\n':
            lines += 1
    print("Number of lines in file is: ", lines) # Just for debuggin, please remove in PROD version


    d = {}

    for i in range(lines):
        line = file.readline()
        l = line.lower().split(' ')
        for item in l:
            if item not in d:
                d[item] = [i+1]
            if item in d:
                d[item].append(i+1)

    return d

print(inverted_index('file.txt'))
```

I would suggest removing stopwords first before creating the inverted index for any meaningful analysis. You can use nltk package for that.